# Not showing asp Label after Visible true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am taking a value and it is showing correctly (using it as a flag). Now we add a validation, but it does not show if it is meeting the validation. why? I dont know.

.aspx.cs

```
if (u.StatusRef.ToString().Equals('1'))
            {
                Email_Sent.Visible = true;
            }
```

.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="statusRef" runat="server"></asp:Label>  <--- This shows the value '1'
<asp:Label ID="Email_Sent" runat="server" hidden="true">Status: You have notified the candidate to confirm references.</asp:Label>
```

Thanks,
EB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
<asp:Label ID="Email_Sent" runat="server" Visible="False">
                                          ^^^^^^^^
```

Instead of `hidden="true"`

Comment: Yes... Hidden and Visible are two different attributes.  To control the visibility, use Visible.  If you want to use Hidden, you have to change the CSS attribute instead.  Visible is easier to work with.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Needed to change the validation also, instead of ' ', used " " and now it worked. Thanks!